# Converting date format sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am taking information from one database with the datetime string formatted like this

```
2011-08-25 13:53:22.607
```

and would like to format it to look like

```
8/25/2011 01:53:22 PM
```

Please suggest a way for me to do this.

Comment: What database engine are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? Oracle? They all have different syntax for these sort of things.

Comment: im using sql server 2008, sorry should have mentioned that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Sql Server try:

```
DECLARE @YourDatetime datetime
SELECT @YourDateTime='2011-08-25 13:53:22.607'

SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(2),month(@YourDateTime))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar(2),day(@YourDateTime))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar(4),year(@YourDateTime)) --date remove leading zeros
    +' '+RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(convert(varchar(50),@YourDateTime,109),14),8)),8)  --amp/pm time format keep leading zeros
    +' '+RIGHT(convert(varchar(50),@YourDateTime,109),2) --am or pm
```

output:

```
----------------------
8/25/2011 01:53:22 PM

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article on date formatting in SQL Server here: http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

It was written with SQL Server 2005 in mind but the information is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native m/d/yyyy style. You can get close (leading 0s on month and day, no leading 0 on hour) with this:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '2011-08-25 13:53:22.607';

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), @d, 101) + ' '
    + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @d, 22), 12));
```

You can do a lot more work to manipulate the strings to get *exactly* the format you're after, but for now I'd suggest doing that formatting in the application/presentation tier instead of arm-wrestling SQL Server into doing it.

In Denali you will be able to use `FORMAT()` with much more control and less ugly string manipulation (a.k.a. manual labor), e.g.

```
SELECT FORMAT(@d, 'M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt');
```